# CSS - Change style of a certain letter

Tags: css, fonts, emoji, fontastic

I want to change the style of a certain letter. So the letter  (U+1F600) has the style `background-image: new-emoji-url;`. Is there any way to do this in CSS? I have tried

```
 {
    background-image: new-emoji.svg;
}
```

But that did not work. What I am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

I have also tried making an Icon Font on fontastic, but the SVG icon gets distorted.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I could offer a solution with javascript if you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this using CSS, you can however use javascript to scan the page on load and wrap all instances of your letter in a span with your custom background, here's an implementation using jQuery:

```
$('div').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(\&#128512;)/g, '<span style="background-image: new-emoji.svg; yellow">$1</span>'));
});
```

Replace the 'div' with the element that contains the character you wish to replace.

Answer (score 2):

First, you cannot directly style a character in CSS. You can style based on tag names, ids, classes, pseudo-elements, pseudo-classes and attributes.

So if you want to replace every "" with your own SVG in your code, you have several ways to achieve it:

1. If you're using PHP, use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php) to look for every instance of your character and replace it with your SVG file as an `<img>` element or an empty tag (e.g.: a `<span>`) with your SVG as a `background-image`.

   ```
   // CSS
   .my-emoji {
       background-image: url(my-emoji.svg);
       // don't forget "display", "height" and "width" attributes
   }

   // PHP
   str_replace("", "<span class='my-emoji'></span>", $my_content);
   // Then output $my_content where you want it.
   ```
2. If you're using Javascript, you can do the same with `replace()`.

   ```
   // CSS
   //same as #1

   // JS
   var res = my_content.replace("", "<span class='my-emoji'></span>");
   // Then output my_content where you want it.
   ```
3. If you have full control on your HTML, you can wrap every instance of "" with a tag and style it with CSS.

   ```
   // HTML
   <span class="my-emoji"></span>

   // CSS
   .my-emoji {
       text-indent: -9999px;
       background-image: url(my-emoji.svg);
       // don't forget "display", "height" and "width" attributes
   }
   ```

Careful not to forget `url()` when using `background-image` in CSS. In your example you gave `background-image: new-emoji.svg`; it would have never worked, it's `background-image: url(new-emoji.svg)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because there are no selectors for letters in css.
If you want you can wrap that specific letter in some tag (with/without class) and use this tag/class to add the css.

If you want you can use javascript for that:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').html(
    $('div').html().split(/i/).join("<span class='colored'>i</span>")
  );
});
```

```css
div span.colored {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is my text</div>
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Yeah, just figured out it is not possible